# Where do I send patches to epstopdf? I made a patch to force B&W PDFs

Tags: epstopdf

I made a small patch to `epstopdf` to force the PDF to B&W. I had a document with some color, and I needed to convert it to a B&W PDF to avoid triggering color separations. Is there a place to post patches to `epstopdf`? I have pasted the patch below.
Regards, William williambader@hotmail.com

```
--- epstopdf-2015   2016-01-18 03:23:20.428744975 +0100
+++ epstopdf-2015-wb    2016-01-18 03:39:10.653914869 +0100
@@ -203,6 +203,7 @@
 $::opt_embed = 1;
 $::opt_exact = 0;
 $::opt_filter = 0;
+$::opt_gray=0;
 $::opt_gs = 1;
 $::opt_gscmd = "";
 @::opt_gsopt = ();
@@ -363,6 +364,7 @@
   --(no)debug        output debugging info  (default: $bool[$::opt_debug])
   --(no)exact        scan ExactBoundingBox  (default: $bool[$::opt_exact])
   --(no)filter       read standard input    (default: $bool[$::opt_filter])
+  --(no)gray         force gray             (default: $bool[$::opt_gray])
   --(no)gs           run ghostscript        (default: $bool[$::opt_gs])
   --(no)hires        scan HiResBoundingBox  (default: $bool[$::opt_hires])

@@ -431,6 +433,7 @@
   "device=s",
   "embed!",
   "exact!",
+  "gray!",
   "filter!",
   "gs!",
   "gscmd=s",              # \ref{val_gscmd}
@@ -585,6 +588,8 @@

 push @GS, '-dUseFlateCompression=false' unless $::opt_compress;

+push @GS, qw(-sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray) if $::opt_gray;
+
 if ($::opt_res and
     not $::opt_res =~ /^(\d+(x\d+)?)$/) {
   warnerr "Invalid resolution: $opt_res";
```

Comment: Try Karl Berry (the editor of TeX Live).

Comment: send it to tex-k@tug.org

Comment: (Shouldn't his post be edited, to obfuscate his address?)

Comment: Thanks, I just sent him an email. The address wasn't on the epstopdf web page, but I just noticed that the tex-k address is at the end of "epstopdf --help" message.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments